# Find and Replace SED

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying find a string in a file and remove from the file inbash script. Using sed find and replace the text but due to forward slash in the string the command is erroring out.
Command :

```
sed -i 's/<host1>Sometext</host1>//g' test.xml

Input 
<test>
   <host1>Sometext</host1>
   <host2>Sometext</host2>
</test>

Output
<test>
</test>
```

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With `sed` try following code. Written and tested in GNU `sed` and your `sed` should support `\n` in it. Written and tested with your shown samples only.

```
sed -E -z 's/>\n.*\n<\//>\n<\//'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With `awk` you could try following code. Written and tested with your shown samples only.

```
awk -v RS= '{sub(/>\n.*\n<\//,">\n<\/")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak '/^ +<.*>/d' input_file
<test>
</test>
```